# Angular 2 built-in or 3rd party components

Tags: angular, angular2-components

I have mostly worked with ASP.NET WebForms and have started learning Angular 2 + TypeScript.  I'm used to having built-in controls such as `CheckBoxList` for common functionality.  For simple things they usually work great, for complex pages that deviate from a control's intended use it can get complicated.  I understand some of the reasoning for the general trend toward being closer to the metal (HTML) instead of having complicated and leaky abstractions, but for simple scenarios I think they are still useful.

I understand I can build my own components for each of these in Angular 2, but that seems like reinventing the wheel.  Are there any built-in components for common/simple scenarios like this?  Or maybe, are there any decent third-party component libraries that I can use?  I'm using TypeScript if it makes any difference.  I can imagine that if I have to build all these components I would probably want to separate out the specific "page view" components that aren't reusable and generic components that are reusable into their own folders.

Comment: I am also started learning Angular 2. I found some of useful component libraries while working [link-1](https://www.npmjs.com/~angular2-material) , [link-2](https://github.com/dharmeshpipariya/md2/tree/master/src/components)